# Делать мне нечего (—/,) телефон отдавать

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Что ставить — запятую или тире?

> Делать мне нечего (—/,) телефон отдавать.

Фраза не моя, поэтому цитирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше так:

*Делать мне нечего, **телефон отдавать**.*

Полная запись: ***Делать мне больше нечего**, (кроме) как телефон отдавать.*

**Смысл такой**: Не буду я его отдавать. Присоединительная интонация **и запятая** сохраняются и в сокращенном варианте.

**Тире?** Тогда смысл фразы становится неясным.